# MySQL Aggregate Row Result Count

Tags: mysql

Is there a simple way in MySQL to return the number of aggregate result rows?

For example:

```
SELECT `name`, SUM(`points`)
FROM `goals`
GROUP BY `name`
HAVING SUM(`points`) > 10
```

If I were looking for number of unique names, if possible, how may I achieve this?

For example, if a return data set is:

Player1 | 11

Player2 | 15

Player3 | 17

Is there a way to return the number of results, which would be three (3)?

Answer (score 0):

Here's one option using a subquery:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM (
    SELECT `name`, SUM(`points`)
    FROM `goals`
    GROUP BY `name`
    HAVING SUM(`points`) > 10
) t
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select count(*) as num_of_records
from
(
  SELECT name
  FROM goals
  GROUP BY name
  HAVING SUM(points) > 10
) tmp
```